# How to use lombok's @Delegate annotations in Java

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I would like to use lombok's `@Delegate` annotations in the my code.
Please check code snippet below and it throws an error saying :`getAge()` is already defined :

```
public interface I {
    String getName();
    int getAge();
}

@Data
public class Vo {
    private String name;
    private long age;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
public class Adapter implements I {

    @Delegate(types = I.class)
    private Vo vo;

    //I want to use my own code here,Because vo.getAge() returns a long,But I.getAge() expects a int
    public int getAge(){
        return (int) vo.getAge();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the lombok [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Delegate):

> To have very precise control over what is delegated and what isn't, write private inner interfaces with method signatures, then specify these private inner interfaces as types in
>
> ```
> @Delegate(types=PrivateInnerInterfaceWithIncludesList.class, excludes=SameForExcludes.class).
> ```

Which means that to include everything in `I`, but exclude only `getAge`, you can  declare an extra inner interface like this:

```
private interface Exclude {
    int getAge();
}
```

and pass it to `exclude`:

```
@Delegate(types = I.class, excludes = Exclude.class)
```